# My network doesnt learn how to memorize noise

Tags: neural-network, keras

I'm trying to implement an idea I have and it involves letting the NN memorize a noise to image mapping of the cifar100 dataset. It uses a custom layer, but even when I replace the custom layer with standard dense ones (in Keras) the network doesn't seem to memorize the relationships (the loss and acc improve slightly and then get stuck), so I'm guessing it's not the custom layer that's in the way. Any thoughts?

```py
examples=50000
n_nodes = 256 * 16 * 16
random_dim = 100
input_tensor = Input(shape=(random_dim,))
noise = np.random.randn(examples, random_dim)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar100.load_data()
model = Sequential()

#MyLayer()
#MyLayer()

model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(n_nodes, input_dim=100))
model.add(Reshape((16, 16, 256)))

model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))

 
model.add(Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same'))


model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(noise, x_train,
                epochs=250,
                batch_size=212,
                shuffle=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code and your question.

To start with, your architecture looks awkward; binary cross-entropy loss with accuracy metric is supposed to be used for classification problems, where the final layer needs to be a single-unit **dense** one with `activation='sigmoid'`. It is not at all clear what your network does here, with the chosen loss function and a convolutional final layer.

Second, since you don't define any activation function, all your layers use the default linear one. Recall from the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/) the Dense layer:

```
keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)
```

where

> **activation**: Activation function to use (see activations). If you don't specify anything, no activation is applied (ie. "linear" activation: a(x) = x).

Since you don't specify explicitly any activation, you actually use a linear one for **all** your layers. And it is well-known that a neural network comprised simply of linear units is equivalent to a simple linear unit (check Andrew Ng's lecture [Why Non-linear Activation Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkOv_k7r6no) for a detailed explanation); in fact, it is only with non-linear activation functions that neural networks begin to be able to do interesting things.

Third, the `input_dim` argument is supposed to be used only for the *first* layer (and not for intermediate ones, as you have done here); in intermediate layers, the input dimension is implicitly calculated as the number of outputs of the *previous* layer. See the SO thread [Keras Sequential model input layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572674/keras-sequential-model-input-layer) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i added relu activations after each layer, but my network still performs exactly the same. its not learning or memorising anything past a point.My loss is stuck at 19302.5799

Comment: @TofaraMoyo as I already said, your architecture & setting both look quite awkward, and it does not look like a well-posed problem. You may want to try [autoencoders](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html)...

Comment: I did get the code from an example of an autoencoder, i want to map a random noise vector to an image, rather than an image back on itself, this should memorise at   least even if it cannot generelise to generating new images with new noise vectors.i have a custom layer built to handle the process of generalisation, but its not learning , so i tried a normal dense layer to see if it would memorise that ,to know wether it was the custom layer or not. i am implementing this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334226867_Dynamic_Encoder_Network_to_Process_Noise_into_Images